# Status{statusCode=PLACES_API_KEY_INVALID, resolution=null}

Tags: android, api, google-places-api

I have 2 different applications using the same key, same dependencies. One works, the second get this error:
Status{statusCode=PLACES_API_KEY_INVALID, resolution=null}

Any clue?
Thanks

Comment: No. At least not, unless you provide any of your code, so we can investigate more closely.

Answer (score 1):

it won't work the generated api key depends on the package name and it's not the same you need to generate an other one.

> Key restriction lets you specify which websites, IP addresses or apps
>   can use this key.

[image]

Comment: Good proposal. I got the SHA key from android studio->Gradle Projects->MyApp->Tasks->android->signingReport and followed yours steps for key restriction  to associate the package name to the SHA key but unfortunately, it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Good proposition. I got the SHA-1 fingerprint from android studio->Gradle projects->MyAppName->(root)->Tasks->android->signingReport and followed your steps to associate it with the package name>.
Unfortunately, it does not solve the problem.
My first basic application which uses the previous API key works, the second which is the integration app fails with the same error.

Comment: same problem ??

Comment: Yes, same problem

Comment: Pb solved by use

 <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
this in place of

 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
             android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

Comment: Thank you sagar15795 commented on 29 Jul 2016 • edited